# Optimization by avoiding object creation

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to avoid creating object by using normal array to store 2 key value, but it does not seems to work.

May I know is there any solution to avoid that one object creation or am I just trying too hard?

Forgotten to ADD:

1) I know why it does not work... I won't be implementing the equals() and hashcode() for key if I don't.

2) Basically I am trying to avoid 1 object creation when retrieving the key.
Usually in the service class there will be a method

```
public void get(String key1, String key2){
       return keyMap.get(new Key(key1,key2)); <>>avoiding the new Key()
}
```

BREAK LINE

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class ArrayMap {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*start A  Possible to get this to work? */
        Map<String[], String> arrMap = new HashMap<>();
        arrMap.put(new String[] { "hello", "hi" }, "hello motto");
        System.out.println(arrMap);
        System.out.println(arrMap.get(new String[] { "hello", "hi" })); // print
                                                                        // null
         /* end of A */

        /*Start of B: Reason: to avoid this */
        Map<Key, String> keyMap = new HashMap<Key, String>();
        keyMap.put(new Key("hello", "hi"), "hello motto"); // I wish to avoid one object creation 

        System.out.println(keyMap.get(new Key("hello", "hi"))); // print
                                                                // "hello motto"
        /*End of B: Reason: to avoid this */
    }
}

class Key {
    private final String key1;
    private final String key2;

    public Key(String key1, String key2) {
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
    }

    public String getKey1() {
        return key1;
    }

    public String getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((key1 == null) ? 0 : key1.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((key2 == null) ? 0 : key2.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Key other = (Key) obj;
        if (key1 == null) {
            if (other.key1 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!key1.equals(other.key1))
            return false;
        if (key2 == null) {
            if (other.key2 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!key2.equals(other.key2))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The key to your map really shouldn't be an Array.

Comment: Actually you are creating the object twice. Which is more than once which is not really optimization. Arrays are object too, so does String. Anyway first rule of optimization is : "Don't do it". I'm not so sure that object creation is a bottleneck in your code.

Comment: I think it would help steer the discussion if you explained **why** you are so keen on avoiding creating the object.

Comment: Also, you should know than an array *is* an object.

Comment: @NPE I am doing it out of fun and interest. lets just assuming less 1 object creation will save the company $1 million dollars.

Comment: If you are doing it out of fun and interest, why ask others to do it for you. Surely the fun and interest lies in working out how to do it for yourself.

Comment: Your `Key#hashCode` implementation is incorrect because: `key1`:`A`, `key2`:`null` is and equivalent hashcode to `key1`:`null`, `key2`:`A`. `HashSet` uses `hashCode` first prior to invoking `equals` when determining object equivalence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May I know is there any solution to avoid that one object creation **or am I just trying too hard?**

If you are unsure whether you're trying too hard, then you probably are. Based on the information you've given us, this looks like premature optimization.

A couple of pertinent points:

1. Object creation is not expensive, especially if the object is short-lived.
2. The only way to be sure of the performance characteristics of a piece of software is through profiling.

Comment: well, maybe I am trying to avoid GC? =x heehee.. anyway can I conclude I am most likely trying too hard?

Comment: @seesee: Until you have profiler results that demonstrate otherwise, it's safe to assume that you're trying too hard :)

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of problems with this approach.

**1. You can't override the `equals()`/`hashcode()` methods for arrays** - This is an issue because the `HashMap` won't be able to correctly determine whether it has looked up the right key or not.

**2. You're still creating new objects every time you want to create a key.** Arrays are objects - you save nothing by creating a new one every time.  Might as well use your original `Key` object.

*Possible Solution*

So I'm going to assume the reason why you want to avoid creating a new object every time is because you're going to be calling `get(key)` on that `HashMap` a LOT.  If that's the case, why not create a mutable `Key` instance that remains internal to your `ArrayMap` object.  Every time you want to key on two `String`s, simply set them in your mutable `Key` instance and use that mutable instance for the lookup.  Then you don't create a new `Key` every time you want to look up a value for a pair of `Strings`.

Answer (score 2):

In these lines

```
arrMap.put(new String[] { "hello", "hi" }, "hello motto");
System.out.println(arrMap);
System.out.println(arrMap.get(new String[] { "hello", "hi" })); // print
                                                                    // null
```

you use a `String[]` as a key. That object doesn't have a custom `equals()` method like the one you have in your `Key` class where you can compare the contents. So when you try to do `map.get()` passing in a new `String[]` (but with the same content), it won't find anything because it's not the same object.

What you might want to do is this

```
String[] array = new String[] { "hello", "hi" };
arrMap.put(array , "hello motto");
System.out.println(arrMap);
System.out.println(arrMap.get(array)); // print hello motto
```

You really shouldn't use array types as keys to Maps.

Answer (score 1):

In java, array1.equals(array2) only if array1 == array2, i.e. they are the same exact instance in memory. So that causes the Map to view them as separate keys.  You're better off going with your Key class for the map's key